# Could not find property 'aild' on source set main

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated to Android Studio 0.5 and Android-Gradle plugin 0.9. Now my project is not refreshing/syncing.

I get the following error:

[image: gradle project refresh error]

I have checked that the `build.gradle` in project root is using the 0.9.+ version of gradle.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is a line in the build.gradle of one of the library projects that I've been using.

```
aild.srcDirs = ['src']
```

Strange that the error never occured before this update. Well removing that line solved the problem.

Thanks for the help anyways guys :)

Comment: Yes, it must be the new Gradle plugin, or the new version of Android Studio or whatever.  So fragile.

Comment: removing is not solution... this would probably remove applicationtest from project

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a typo. Change 'aild' to 'aidl'.

Comment: change it where? I've not used it anywhere.. That error ocurred after I updated gradle plugin and android studio

Comment: try clean and rebuild project from `Build` menu.